# OnTextChanged Event fires but when i move the mouse position

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, gridview, linq-to-sql, textbox

I have to change the `gridview` data when ever the text is changed in the search box.

**PROBLEM**:

`gridview` data changes but when i move the mouse position. How do i make it possible that i don't have to move the mouse position.

**CODE**:

```
<asp: TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
      OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default.Instead of **TextChanged** you can use **KeyUp** or **KeyDown** events with **JavaScript** and after trigerring the events  catch the `form` and **submit** it with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @SurenSrapyan , it is helpful to me.